# Simplify a double root expression to least operations

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How can I simplify this expression further so that it has the least amount of operations. WA is no help at all. $$\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{8x+1}-1}2}$$

I'm not looking for complicated equations, all I want to do is use less operations in the above. By less operations, I mean for example taking one square root is one operation. Simple algebra operations too. Even one less operation is fine.

Please do not just say it's impossible. If you think it is impossible, please prove(or some explanation) why.

Comment: it already in the simple form..what do  you want to do exactly, And more over  simpling further will give meaning when you are explaining what is the next step you want to do.@user330725

Comment: @gloom Simplest form does not always mean that it has less operations.

Comment: $\sqrt{\frac {\sqrt {8x+1}-1}2}$ which involves 6 operations, $\sqrt{}$, $\div$,$+$, $\sqrt{}$, $+$ and $\times $ respectively. Now, if you are replacing the expression by $\sqrt{\sqrt{2x+0.25}-0.5}$ then it involves only 5 operations. Do you want like this???

Comment: @gloom Yes, any simpler than that